# Why does T-SQL OpenXML bust with certain characters?

Tags: xml, t-sql, openxml

I have the following XML that I'm running in SQL Server, and it breaks, why?

```
 declare @xml varchar(max)
 declare @hDoc int

 set @xml = '<transaction>
 <item itemId="1" value="Hello World" />
 <item itemId="2" value="Hello &World" />
 <item itemId="3" value="Hello <World" />
 <item itemId="4" value="Hello >World" />
 <item itemId="5" value="Hello ’World" />
 </transaction>'

 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml

 select
        itemId
 ,      value
 from
     openxml(@hDoc, '/transaction/item')
    with (
         itemId int,
         value varchar(max)
     ) item
```

Comment: That curly apostrophe sucked an hour and a half of my life so I wanted to put it into google's results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the XML contain invalid characters.  For XML in general you must escape the less than sign and the ampersand like so: &lt; and &amp;

```
 declare @xml varchar(max)
 declare @hDoc int

 set @xml = '<transaction>
 <item itemId="1" value="Hello World" />
 <item itemId="2" value="Hello &amp;World" />
 <item itemId="3" value="Hello &lt;World" />
 <item itemId="4" value="Hello >World" />
 </transaction>'

 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml

 select
        itemId
 ,      value
 from
     openxml(@hDoc, '/transaction/item')
    with (
         itemId int,
         value varchar(max)
     ) item
```

However when using openxml certain values won't work in general, specifically that curly apostrophe.  I'm not sure what values are invalid, but I know that is one of them.  So the solution is to use the native XML type in SQL Server 2005.

```
 declare @xml xml
 set @xml = '<transaction>
 <item itemId="1" value="Hello World" />
 <item itemId="2" value="Hello &amp;World" />
 <item itemId="3" value="Hello &lt;World" />
 <item itemId="4" value="Hello >World" />
 <item itemId="5" value="Hello ’World" />
 </transaction>'

 select
       item.value('@itemId', 'int')
     , item.value('@value', 'varchar(max)')
 from @xml.nodes('/transaction/item') [transaction](item)
```

Comment: Close enough, but it's a little more complicated, too.  Xml spec defines a very large swath of unicode as 'allowed', and anything outside of that is not allowed and must be escaped.  Since unicode is very large, there are still a LOT of other characters not mentioned here that must be escaped.

Comment: You mean characters that won't work with openxml like the curly apostrophe, or you mean characters like ampersand and less than that must be encoded?  I thought only those two and "->&quot; had to encoded for XML...

Answer (score 0):

If possible, assemble your XML document in the application. The framework (.Net, Java, ...?) will do the proper oncoding for you, and will yield valid XML.